# Doubly linked list returns "List is empty"

Tags: c

I am  beginner in C and trying to create doubly linked list by char variable. I did same thing in single list. However, when I make same thing in doubly list, my check function that checks whether list is empty or not, returns list is empty and so my list is not written by my print function. I have read some posts that related with my problem and I think it is about referencing of pointer but I could not fix my problem. Since this is my first post and English is not my native language, I am sorry for occasional imperfections. So please warn me about my mistakes to share post correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node{
char val;

struct node *next;
struct node *prev;

}node_t;




void pushFront(node_t  *nodes);
int isEmpty(node_t *nodes);
void printList(node_t *nodes);
void pushBack(node_t *nodes);

int main(void)
{

node_t *head=NULL;  //My head node

pushFront(head);
pushBack(head);
printList(head);
}



int isEmpty(node_t *nodes)//Checking whether node is empty or not.
{
node_t *current=nodes;
if(current==NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

void pushFront(node_t *nodes)
{

node_t *newNode;
char b;
int i;

do{
printf("Enter a char:");//Getting character from user
scanf(" %c",&b);

if(isEmpty(nodes))//If node is empty then create
{
    newNode=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->val=b;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->prev=NULL;

    nodes=newNode;

}


else//if it is not empty, get new first character
{
    newNode=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->val=b;
    nodes->prev=newNode;
    newNode->next=nodes;
    nodes=newNode;

}
printf("Enter a -1 to exit:");//If user wants to continue to add head 
character
scanf("%d",&i);


}while(i!=-1);
}



void pushBack(node_t *nodes)//adding character to back of head
{
node_t *current=nodes;
char b;
int i;

do{
    printf("Enter a char:");
    scanf(" %c",&b);

    if(isEmpty(nodes))//checking again empty or not
    {
        node_t *newNode=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        newNode->val=b;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->prev=NULL;
        nodes=newNode;
    }
    else//if not empty
    {
        while(current->next!=NULL)
        {
            current=current->next;
        }
        current->next=malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->next->val=b;
        current->next->prev=current;
        current->next->next=NULL;
    }
    printf("Enter -1 to exit:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    }while(i!=-1);
    }

    void printList(node_t *nodes)//Printing all the characters
    {

    if(isEmpty(nodes))
    {
    printf("List is empty");
    }
    else
    {
    while(nodes!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%c",nodes->val);
        nodes=nodes->next;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your fix-my-code question is off-topic here. Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step and query its state, thus understanding your bugs.

Comment: `void pushFront(node_t  *nodes);` --> `node_t  *pushFront(node_t  *nodes);`, `pushFront(head);` --> `head = pushFront(head);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, you are right. I will follow this steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but it should give you a hint:

Question:

```
void Foo(int bar)
{
  bar = bar * 2;
}

...
int x = 3;
Foo(x);
// what's the value of x here ?
```

What's the value of `x` after the call `Foo(x)`?

Well, the same thing is happening with `pushFront`, and `pushBack`.

Comment: It becomes 6 after function calling. I got it and I reconsider it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HalilArslan no it doesn't, the value of `x` will remain `3`.BTW if you'd call `Foo(3)`, what would happen?

Comment: If it remains 3 , it means, we copy x inside function ? I think Foo(3) results 6 but I am confused.

Comment: @HalilArslan if you don't believe it, why don't you just [__try it out__](https://www.ideone.com/nxdrwe)? And reading your C textbook would be a very good idea as well.

Comment: I tried but I confused about  example you gave, sorry. I am just thinking. @Michael Walz

Comment: @HalilArslan be aware that parameters are passed by _value_ in C. Every C textbook teaches you this.

Comment: @HalilArslan I enhanced the [__example here__](https://www.ideone.com/nxdrwe).

Comment: yes, I have read but sorry, I have to read it again. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem and solution. Thanks again.